# Use TTF fonts in windows phone xna games

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna, spritefont

I used a TTF font installed in my pc in a windows phone xna game.(as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446159/windows-phone-7-how-to-use-ttf-in-spritefont))
As the font is already installed in pc, it works perfectly on the emulator.
As I didn't import the font in to the project, I am not quite sure will it work on devices.

Can anyone tell me will it work fine in the devices?
Did I do it in the correct way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XNA content pipeline generates a sprite font at build time and packages it with your game. The original TrueType font doesn't need to be installed on the phone.

Of course, the best way to be sure is get an actual Windows Phone device and try it.

Comment: Thanks, very much. I was in a big hesitation.